# ES6 Deconstructing an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have this object

```
const config = {
    js: {
        files: [
            {
                src: './js/app.js',
                name: 'script.js',
                dest: 'public_html/js/'
            },
            {
                src: './js/admin.js',
                name: 'script.js',
                dest: 'public_html/js/'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

and I want to get this (getting all the sources):

```
sources = ['./js/app.js', './js/admin.js']

// or, at least
sources = [{'./js/app.js'}]
```

I know how to do it with a loop, but can I do it with ES6 deconstructing?

Something like:

```
{sources = [{src}]} = config.js;
```

OR

```
{[{src}] : sources} = config.js;
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use destructuring over a loop? Or even, a simple `map`?

Comment: Just use a loop. Don't try to force the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: `var sources = config.js.files.map(e => e.src)`

Comment: Just wanted to see how far I can push destructure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Destructuring is not meant for a case such as this. Simply using `map()` will easily get the job done.

```js
const config = {
    js: {
        files: [
            {
                src: './js/app.js',
                name: 'script.js',
                dest: 'public_html/js/'
            },
            {
                src: './js/admin.js',
                name: 'script.js',
                dest: 'public_html/js/'
            }
        ]
    }
};

console.log(config.js.files.map(x => x.src));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use destructuring with an iterator like [`Array#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) and a [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and a temporary variable `index`.

```js
var config = { js: { files: [{ src: './js/app.js', name: 'script.js', dest: 'public_html/js/' }, { src: './js/admin.js', name: 'script.js', dest: 'public_html/js/' }] } },
    index,
    result = [];

for ({ 0: index, 1: { src: result[index] } } of config.js.files.entries());

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to destructure something like this without a loop or map due to the array.

You can use destructuring in a for-of loop to iterate through the files:

```
let srcs = [];
for (let {src} of config.js.files) {
  srcs.push(src);
}
```

But a better approach would be to use array methods:

```
// using map
let srcs = config.js.files.map(file => file.src);

// or by using reduce
let srcs = config.js.files.reduce((result, file) => result.concat(file.src), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript [**Array.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

**DEMO**

```js
const config = {
    js: {
        files: [
            {
                src: './js/app.js',
                name: 'script.js',
                dest: 'public_html/js/'
            },
            {
                src: './js/admin.js',
                name: 'script.js',
                dest: 'public_html/js/'
            }
        ]
    }
};

var res = config.js.files.map(function(item) {
  return item.src;
});

console.log(res);
```